# Django authentication is alway false for non superuser

Tags: python, django, authentication

here is the trouble i try to autheticate the users for my website but `authenticate()` return alway the None value for the user created with the registration page. I can correctly log user after their user user creation and the entry is in the database. I have a custom user model extended form `AbstractBaseUser`. So here is the portion of code not working :

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as authlog

    def login(request):
    error = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            print("Validated form.")
            print(username)
            print(password)
            print(user)

            if user:
                print("Logged user.")
                authlog(request, user)
                return redirect(to='home')
            else:
                print("Not logged user.")
                error = True
    else:
        form = forms.LoginForm()

    return render(request, 'users/login.html', locals())
```

And in the following block of code the user is sccessfully logged after it's registration.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as authlog

def register(request):
    form = forms.RegisterForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        authlog(request, user)
        return redirect(to='home')


print('Registered new user')
return render(request, 'users/register.html', locals())
```

What i don't understant is why it the admin account i created with `./manage.py createsuperuser` work and not the others.
And also i can't create user in the admin panel and i don't know why.

Thanks :D

EDIT: My forms

```
class CreateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    pass1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    pass2 = forms.CharField(label="Password Check", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = '__all__'

        def clean_pass2(self):
            pass1 = self.cleaned_data.get('pass1')
            pass2 = self.cleaned_data.get('pass2')
            if pass1 and pass2 and pass1 != pass2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")

            return pass2

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(UserCreationForm, self)
            if user.exte:
                user.promo = None
                user.login = None
            user.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["pass1"])
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user

class RegisterForm(CreateUserForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('email', 'lname', 'fname', 'exte', 'promo', 'login')

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Mot de passe', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

About the cleaned data i log the data i get for debug purpose and they're right.

EDIT2: My User Model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True,  verbose_name='e-mail')
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='first name', null=False, blank=False)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='last name', null=False, blank=False)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="login")
    promo = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="promotion")
    exte  = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="externe")
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='active user')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='admin user')

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fname', 'lname']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.fname, self.lname)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.lname

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
```

Comment: Please show your `RegisterForm`.

Comment: what exactly is this supposed to be doing? `if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save()` you probably want to use something like `get cleaned data`...

Comment: @hansTheFranz That's pretty standard code for a [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: can you show your models.py ?

Comment: Is that your actual indentation (in the form)?

Comment: I just updated the indent

Comment: @knbk Oh i did not know that. sorry. Can you show me in the link you posted where this is referenced? I always thought its `request username` and then login user like its explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

I really don't want to be a smart aleck here, I just want to learn it the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an indentation problem on your form. Your `save` method (as well as the `clean_pass2` method) are wrongly indented inside the inner Meta class, so it won't be seen by the form itself. This means that `set_password` won't be called when you create the user, so the password will not be hashed.

Move those methods one indent to the left.

Comment: It seem logic but now i have an error i don't understand (sorry it's one of my first python projects)

    `File "/home/thor/Projects/bdewebsite/users/forms.py", line 24, in save
    if user.exte:
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'exte'`

Comment: Your syntax is wrong; you need to call the method on super: `user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)`. Also note you don't need that call to `user.save(commit=False)`.

Comment: Thanks i just foudn the solution :D You solved the problem i wwas bumping on since two days thank you so much :D